# The child node "transport" at path "enqueue_elastica" must be configured

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, enqueue

In a Symfony 4.3 app with `friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle` 5.1.0, `enqueue/elastica-bundle` 0.9.3, and `enqueue/fs` 0.9.12 installation of the latter ends with:

> The child node "transport" at path "enqueue_elastica" must be
>   configured.

I've tried multiple permutations in `enqueue.yaml`, including [the only example](https://tech.yappa.be/enqueue-symfony-console-commands) I've found.

enqueue.yaml:

```
enqueue:
    default:
        transport: '%env(resolve:ENQUEUE_DSN)%'
        client: ~
```

.env includes:

```
###> enqueue/enqueue-bundle ###
ENQUEUE_DSN=null://
###< enqueue/enqueue-bundle
```

Elasticsearch 6.8 is installed. Relatively simple indexes are readily created.  A more complex index fails with running out of memory - thus the need for `enqueue`.

What is an appropriate configuration of `enqueue.yaml` for filesystem transport?

Edit: Curiously, the Ubuntu 18 Hyper-V virtual machine was able to slog through the populating without `enqueue` while the Windows host failed at 94200/156865.

Comment: Behavior was improved but not resolved by increasing PHP's memory limit. Still would like to see a proper config for `enqueue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seemingly correct config has:

.env:

```
...
###> enqueue/enqueue-bundle ###
ENQUEUE_DSN="file://%VAR_DIR%/enqueue"
###< enqueue/enqueue-bundle ###
```

This needed to accompanied by

enqueue.yaml:

```
enqueue:
    default:
        transport:
            dsn: '%env(resolve:ENQUEUE_DSN)%'
            path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/queue' ## probably just a placeholder
        client: ~
```

While the above avoids any errors being thrown it does not allow the populating to complete. I'm officially stuck. Time to look at reducing index complexity and multi index searches.

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```
enqueue_elastica:
    transport: '%enqueue.default_transport%'
    doctrine: ~
```

In your `enqueue.yaml` config